# How do I go back from page, where I experienced an error OnAppearing()?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

What I have is:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
        base.OnAppearing();
        try
        {
            candyStore.Start();
        }
        catch (UriFormatException e)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Couldn't find a store to load from", "OK");
            StoreNavigationPage.Current.PopAsync();
        }
    }
```

That popAsync is just method inherited from NavigationPage. However, when I'm catching an exception, pages does'n change (doesn't pop). Maybe I'm doing something wrong? ( I'm testing it on Android) 
Thanks

Comment: Thank you all guys for the answers! I fixed the problem by myself. The problem was that I didn't `await` alert. So I just made a private async method which is awaiting for the result of alert and then PopAsync page back.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync()` to go back

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, it throws an exception saying that PopAsync is not globally supported on Android.

Comment: @Petr can you use PopModalAsync?

Answer (score 0):

you should call

```
this.Navigation.PopAsync()
```

when you have message "PopAsync is not globally supported on Android", that means, that is you have nested navigation pages, you should call PopAsync() on deepest one

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't `await` alert. So I just made a `private async` method which is awaiting for the result of alert and then `PopAsync` page back.

Comment: You should accept your own question as the answer. Prefably you include a code snippet of the solution for future visitors that have the same issue.